# Can't stop audio playback on iOS with Codename One

Tags: iphone, codenameone

My Codename One app features audio playback in the background when the user taps the screen. The audio I use is an mp3. Here is how I use the Media playback :

```
public static void playSound(boolean stop) {

 sound.reset(); // The input stream needs to go back to the beginning
 Media myClip = MediaManager.createMedia(sound, "audio/mp3", () -> {
                // If there is no order to stop playback, we keep playing when it has completed (looping)
                playSound(false);
            });

            if (!stop) {
                myClip.play();
            } else {
                myClip.cleanup();
            }
}
```

So hen the user taps the screen components change and I pass true to `playSound` method. On Android the current playback stops not on iOS with an iPhone 4.

Please note that when the app gets minimized (center button pressed) the playback stops (even if I don't call `cleanup()` on the `Media` which I do on Android to stop the playback when the app is minimized).

How can I stop the playback on iPhone ?

Any help appreciated,

Comment: Don't you create a new media instance every time and only stop that new media instead of the one playing?

Comment: Thanks Shai for pointing me in the right direction. So I declared `myClip` further up, but it was not sufficient. I had to `createMedia` only `if (myClip == null || !myClip.isPlaying())` to prevent a Media to be in the wild without any possibility to stop it. I was distracted by the fact that it worked on Android!

Answer (score 1):

@Shai pointed me to the right direction so here is the code finally used :

```
Media myClip = null;

public static void playSound(boolean stop) {

 sound.reset(); // The input stream needs to go back to the beginning



  /**
  * If the media is playing we don't create it
  * otherwise we would have several media in the wild 
  * that could not be stopped
  */
 if (myClip == null || !myClip.isPlaying()) {

      myClip = MediaManager.createMedia(sound, "audio/mp3", () -> {
                // If there is no order to stop playback, we keep playing when it has completed (looping)
                playSound(false);
            });
     }

            if (!stop) {
                myClip.play();
            } else {
                myClip.cleanup();
            }
}
```